# How to mitigate locking in stored procedure that queries cross-database view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, locking

I have a view that joins SQL Server tables on linked servers. There are certain restrictions on linked servers that mean I can't create an index on the view and there is a stored procedure that last night locked the database, even though it is only doing a select. The stored procedure is generated by [.NetTiers](http://nettiers.com/Home.ashx) (I've elided a dozen columns from both select statements):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AbnormalReadingSource_Get]
(
    @WhereClause varchar (2000)  ,
    @OrderBy varchar (2000)  ,
    @PageIndex int   ,
    @PageSize int   
)
AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound int
    DECLARE @PageUpperBound int

    -- Set the page bounds
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex
    SET @PageUpperBound = @PageLowerBound + @PageSize

    IF (@OrderBy is null or LEN(@OrderBy) < 1)
    BEGIN
        -- default order by to first column
        SET @OrderBy = '[Result]'
    END

    -- SQL Server 2005 Paging
    declare @SQL as nvarchar(4000)
    SET @SQL = 'WITH PageIndex AS ('
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT'
    IF @PageSize > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' TOP ' + convert(nvarchar, @PageUpperBound)
    END
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @OrderBy + ') as RowIndex'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ', [Result]'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM [AbnormalReadingSource]'
    IF LEN(@WhereClause) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE ' + @WhereClause
    END
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ) SELECT'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' [Result],'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM PageIndex'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE RowIndex > ' + convert(nvarchar, @PageLowerBound)
    IF @PageSize > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND RowIndex <= ' + convert(nvarchar, @PageUpperBound)
    END
    exec sp_executesql @SQL

    -- get row count
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRowCount'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM [AbnormalReadingSource]'
    IF LEN(@WhereClause) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE ' + @WhereClause
    END
    exec sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

The database transaction isolation level is `READ COMMITTED` so setting the isolation level in the stored procedure isn't necessary but is in the .NetTiers templates used to generate the stored procedure. Can I use the *readpast* hint to avoid the locking that occurred? Do I need to provide any other hints when using *readpast*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try READPAST but remember it will not allow "dirty" reads so your result set could be missing some records if something is momentarily locked.

Similarly you could try your select statement with: `WITH(NOLOCK)`

NOLOCK will read the "dirty" data but then you run the risk of it being rolled back.

Both will avoid blocking, both have their pros and cons.

This article should help clarify:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-nolock-and-readpast-table-hints-in-sql-server/6185492

Answer (score 2):

Run **SQL Profiler** in conjunction with this query, and then feed it into the Database Engine Tuning Advisor. Do not change your isolation levels if you can either break this up, or improve your indices.

You may create views on linked servers but those linked servers must **both be SQL Server** and Cross Database Queries Not Allowed in an Indexed View.

**Perhaps this procedure should not be running via a view at all.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

Great locking articles

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75722
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323630

Do not use the word sp in your stored procedures, those are reserved for system stored procedures will cause minor overhead.

Cursors are bad, but better indexing is the primarily solution, which of course the Tuning Advisor will scrip for you automatically, which means you need to circumvent views altogether to leverage.

Create fault alerts regarding this process so both you and your co-manager is aware if this task fails when you are out-of-office via SSIS SMTP tasks.

"To repeatedly get data from another server, create a linked server and then use the OPENQUERY function or use 4-part naming. If you are not adhered with T-SQL, then it is better to use import/export wizard, and you can save it as a SSIS package for future use." [- SQL Server MVP Pinal Dave](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42547/SQL-SERVER-How-To-Handle-Deadlock)

**Regarding the locking and potential deadlocking**

**Typical methods you can use to resolve deadlocks include:**

- Adding and dropping indexes.
- Adding index hints.
- Modifying the application to access resources in a similar pattern.
- Removing activity from the transaction like triggers.
- Keeping transactions as short as possible.

  In SQL Server, you can also minimize locking contention while protecting transactions from dirty reads of uncommitted data modifications using either:

  - The READ COMMITTED isolation level **with the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option set to ON.**
  - The SNAPSHOT isolation level.

Load SQL Profiler with a focus on locking, initiate the scripts which deadlock specifically for that DB and feed it into the Database Engine Tuning Adviser, and review the suggestions.

**Footnotes**:
[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42547/SQL-SERVER-How-To-Handle-Deadlock)

[[1]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42547/SQL-SERVER-How-To-Handle-Deadlock

Prior Stackoverflow locking question [how to solve deadlock problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928830/how-to-solve-deadlock-problem)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just set the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL to `READ UNCOMMITTED` you will pretty much have the same result as using READPAST or with NOLOCK

I know you said that the procedure is generated by .NetTiers but since you said you can add a query hint (readpast) I assume you can change the isolation level too.

Comment: Thanks Diego - in this case I'm going to go with readpast but I appreciate that I could also have used your suggestion.