# Deadlock on indexed view

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, isolation-level, indexed-view

I have been pulling my hair on this deadlock:

[image: Deadlock]

[[Enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpVY5.png)]

IX_OrderAmounts is an indexed view doing aggregations on the Amount table. The transaction on the left (Repeatable read - although same happens with Read commited) only inserts a single row in the Amount table. The transaction on the right (Read committed) updates a few rows (2 - 3 rows) from the Amount table (all in one UPDATE statement).

Now what I don't get is why the transaction on the left, which only needs to insert a row, needs to acquire a second update lock.

Because the deadlock is on the indexed view that I don't update directly, I can't really use SQL hints (or at least I don't know how).

How can I resolve this deadlock?

Comment: Please post the execution plan of the left statement. Preferably as XML (.sqlplan).

Comment: The right hand query seems to be asking for an exclusive lock.  You could try the `with (rowlock)` hint.

Comment: The execution plan is here: http://sdrv.ms/150WPut

Comment: On the left, does the *statement* or the *transaction* insert a single row? In the plan shown only one U-lock should be taken (and upgraded to X). So was there a previous statement which might have picked up a lock? Was there any previous DML on that indexed view?

Comment: No, previous statements in the transaction only read the indexed view, so they should at most have a shared lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typical methods you can use to resolve deadlocks include:**

- Adding and dropping indexes.
- Adding index hints.
- Modifying the application to access resources in a similar pattern.
- Removing activity from the transaction like triggers.
- Keeping transactions as short as possible.

  In SQL Server, you can also minimize locking contention while protecting transactions from dirty reads of uncommitted data modifications using either:

  - The READ COMMITTED isolation level **with the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option set to ON.**
  - The SNAPSHOT isolation level.

Load SQL Profiler with a focus on locking, initiate the scripts which deadlock specifically for that DB and feed it into the Database Engine Tuning Adviser, and review the suggestions.

**Footnotes**:
[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42547/SQL-SERVER-How-To-Handle-Deadlock)

[[1]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42547/SQL-SERVER-How-To-Handle-Deadlock

Prior Stackoverflow locking question [how to solve deadlock problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928830/how-to-solve-deadlock-problem)